# CSS, Javascript or jQuery blinking element on load

Tags: jquery, css, delay, fade, pageload

**This is what should happen.**

1. Page loads
2. It does nothing for 1 second
3. Then it makes the element "blink" four times (with about 600 ms delay)
4. Done!

**Language to use**

Use CSS, Javascript or jQuery to solve it. It should work on common browsers and devices.

**The blink**

With blink I mean fade from one background color to another. The fade-time should be changable.

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/cjkkr5h0/

**HTML**

```
<div>Make me blink 4 times on load (600 ms)!</div>

<p>CSS, Javascript or jQuery. Make it simple, make it short. Should work on mobile devices and common browser versions.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: #90a5b7;

    /* NOT SO IMPORTANT */
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.blink-to {
    background: #2a5b84;
}
```

How is it done the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yc3r82uy/)

```
var count = 0
// DOES NOTHING FOR 1 SEC
setTimeout(function () {
  var interval = setInterval(function () {

      $("#blinker").toggleClass(function(){
          count++
          return "blink"
      });

     // Reason it is 8 because it is counting the fadeIn and FadeOut  
     if (count == 8) 
         clearInterval(interval);

    }, 600)
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that on jquery. Here it is a possible solution

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
        var timesRun = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            if(timesRun == 4){
                return;
            }
            timesRun++;

            if($("#blinker").css('display') == 'none' )
                $("#blinker").css('display','block');
            else
                $("#blinker").css('display','none') ;
        }, 600);
    });
```

where the blinker its the id of the tag you want to toggle on off..
anyway i just read that by blinking you meant switching colors, just change the if else statement to match the proportie of color and the colors you want to switch.